# Despite adding a break statement, if condition still moves on and prints out incorrect error message

Tags: c, do-while

So for an assignment I am supposed to check the input from a user and determine whether:

1. if there are characters in the input: I print an error message saying it is an invalid input and ask for input again until it is valid
2. if there are less than 6 digits in the input: I print an error message that there are x many digits remaining and ask for input again until it is valid
3. 

```
int main() {
    int solutionArray[6];
    int guessArray[6];
    int indexArray[6];

    /*Creating the random numbers and asking for seed*/
    
    int seed;
    printf("Enter the integer value of the seed for the game: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);
    srand(seed);

    /*Adding the randomized integers into solutionArray*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            solutionArray[i] = rand() % 10;
            printf("%3d", solutionArray[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    /*Game interface*/
    printf("For each turn enter 6 digits 0 <= digit <= 9 \n");
    printf("Spaces or tabs in your response will be ignored. \n");


    /*Validating conditions of the user input*/
    char input[50];
    int error = 0;
    int enoughDigits = 0;

    do {
        printf("Enter your guess, 6 digits: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        int numCount = 0;
        int remainder = 0;
        int maxLength = 6;

        // Checking to see if there are any characters other than digits and prints error
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (!isdigit(input[i])) {
                printf("ERROR: A character in your guess was not a digit or a white space\n");
                printf("\n");
                error = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        /*Checking to see if enough digits have been inputted*/ 
        remainder = 6 - numCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            if (isdigit(input[i] == 1)){
                numCount++;
                if (numCount < maxLength && numCount != 0){
                enoughDigits = 1;
            }
                else{
                    printf("You need to enter %d digits to complete your guess \n", remainder);
            }
            error = 1;
            }
        }
        
        // Print the guess if there are no errors
        if (error == 0) {
            printf("Your guess was:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                guessArray[i] = input[i] - '0';
                printf("%2d", guessArray[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        // Printing results of the guesses 
        int partialMatches = 0;
        int perfectMatches = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            partialMatches = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                if (solutionArray[i] == guessArray[j]) {
                    partialMatches++;
                    break;  // Exit inner loop after finding a partial match
                }
            }
            if (solutionArray[i] == guessArray[i]) {
                perfectMatches++;
                partialMatches--;
            }
        }
        if (perfectMatches == 6){
            printf("YOU DID IT! ! \n");
            error = 0;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d matches, %d partial matches\n",perfectMatches, partialMatches);
        error = 1; 

    } while (error == 1 || enoughDigits == 1);

return 0;
}
```

My issue comes in when the user inputs for example "123" it should print that I need to enter 3 more digits but it only prints "A character in your guess was not a digit or a whitespace". For some reason it prints that error regardless of the input.

Attached is my code below. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by checking `strlen(input)` to make sure the user actually gave six characters as input.

Comment: Actually, even before that, you need to check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: You are WIDE-OPEN to exploit by buffer-overflow using `scanf("%s", input);`. When using `"%s"` to fill an array you MUST use the *field-width* modifier to limit the number of characters to `size-1`, e.g. `scanf("%49s", input);`. Additionally, you cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. You may want to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` and just be aware the `'\n'` generated by pressing `[Enter]` will be included in the string filled by `fgets()` (which you trim using `strcspn()`)

Comment: You check the first six characters in the buffer, even when only 3 were entered.  So, when it checks the null byte, that is invalid — and it points this out quite correctly.  You need to worry about overlong as well as short strings.

Comment: What if MORE than 6-digits are entered? Do you say `"X too many?"`

Comment: Also, are you sure you are supposed to check for partial matches and report the details of each digit? Seems like for a number guessing game with a 6 digits random to guess you would simply generate a 6 digit random and then give some number of tries (e.g. 20) to try and guess the 6-digit number. You can enforce all your input criteria on the random seen and each guess -- but the rest of your code seems like it may be headed in the wrong direction (could be perfectly fine -- you haven't specified what the rest of the assignment is)

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems

**Buffer overflow**

`scanf("%s", input)` does not prevent too many characters in saving to `input[]`.  Use a *width*.  Since `input` is size 50, use a width of 49.

```
scanf("%49s", input)
```

**Wrong test**

`isdigit(input[i] == 1)` certainly should be `isdigit(input[i])` to test if `input[i]` is a digit.